# Repurpose the S3 tag synonym

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

[s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s3) is currently a synomym for [amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3) which seems weirdly overreaching and wasteful — especially considering that [“S3” is the name of an (extremely well established) object system for the R programming language](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S3.html).

What’s more, [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) and [r6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r6) are existing tags that refer to the appropriate R object systems (yes, R has different frequently used object systems … amongst them S3, S4 and R6). S3 is by far the most commonly used, and [s4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s4) already has a sizeable number of questions.

Could the [s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s3) synonym be repurposed accordingly? It would be a quite useful tag. Here’s an [example question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39470750/1968) where it would have been needed. Note how the OP instead put the tag into the title: exactly what Stack Overflow wants to avoid.

To support this further with arguments, the official name of Amazon S3 is, well, “[Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html)”. Whereas “R S3” is a non-existent term, so no R user (me included) would ever think of trying to tag their question as [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3). It’s therefore natural to use the tag [amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3), and with a proper tag description we could avoid most mistaggings. But as we can see from statistics, nobody uses the [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3) tag so mistagging of R questions about S3 is rampant, and this won’t change.

Comment: There are over 650 open [R questions that mention S3 but not Amazon](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+s3+is%3Aquestion+-amazon+closed%3Ano). Over 100 of those don't have any answers. Properly tagging them couldn't hurt. (And shouldn't hurt the `amazon-s3` tag, since people should already see it suggested when typing in the `amazon` tag.)

Comment: In the vast majority of cases when someone refers simply to S3, they're referring to the AWS technology. These acronyms are so widely used and understood, that most AWS developers wouldn't even think to include the "aws" first when tagging a question. If it's changed, it will cause a lot of confusion. I think the tag should stay as it is.

Comment: @user1751825 See answer and discussion below. You have a point, but there is an actively used, unambiguous way of referring to Amazon S3. There’s currently no such way to refer to S3 in the context of R. To repeat my argument from below: you argue that mistagging will happen. You ignore that it’s *already* happening, in the opposite direction. And this cannot be fixed in any other way, because no R user would ever think of using the [tag:r-s3] tag: the term doesn’t exist. Whereas [tag:amazon-s3] is not only a well-established term — it’s the official name.

Comment: This will just lead to mistagging, as Mark Amery noted. Using `r-s3`, even if it's not pretty enough, would be a much better idea.

Comment: @ssube As mentioned repeatedly, mistagging is *already* happening on this subject. Are you saying it would get worse? Because *that’s* the contentious point, not whether mistagging will happen.

Comment: If anything, S3 should be used for the programming language by that name (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S3_(programming_language)), but I guess nobody would be interested in that these days ;)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hmm, good point. I actually feel that programming languages in general should take precedence.

Answer (score 19):

[amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3) has over 15000 questions; [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3) has less than 50, and [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) questions mentioning S3 only number in the hundreds. If you make this change, I predict that the overwhelming majority of stuff tagged [s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/s3) is going to be mistagged questions about Amazon S3 and the poor souls following [r-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-s3) are going to have to do a whole load of janitorial work that they currently don't.

Maybe I'm wrong, and others are welcome to provide data from previous similar scenarios, but based upon my best guess of the outcome I would advise against this. You're probably just going to end up screwing over the subcommunity you're trying to help.

Comment: I would challenge your prediction: I expect that it doesn’t follow from the data (especially if a clear description is given). The `r-s3` tag isn’t used because nobody knows about it (including me, until now). The difference between “Amazon S3” and “R S3” is that the former is actually referred to as “Amazon S3” ([source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html), and “S3” is simply a shorthand in the context of Amazon services). Whereas “R S3” isn’t a thing: it’s simply called “S3” in the context of R. Nobody calls it “R S3”, either officially or unofficially.

Comment: Even granting that `r-s3` isn't used because nobody knows it exists, there are still mere hundreds of `r` questions mentioning S3. That means you're going to have over an order of magnitude difference between AWS users and R users. Even if only 1 in 10 askers with an Amazon S3 problem mistags, it'll still make up the majority of the content on the S3 tag.

Comment: Maybe we should introduce messages like the following: “You tried to tag [s3], but such a tag does not exist. Did you mean [amazon-s3], [r-s3], …”, where the ordering of the list should obviously depend on the other tags already given.

Comment: @HermannDöppes similar to wikipedia's disambiguation pages?

Comment: @briantist That didn't occur to me. (= I was thinking more along the lines of a nice little message (or popup) like we already have here on SO, instead of a full blown, overladen site.

Comment: @MarkAmery Exactly: *if* they mistag. Clearly you and I estimate the likelihood of this drastically differently: mistags will happen, but almost certainly not at a rate of 1/10. With a proper tag description, I’d wager that the rate is orders of magnitude less. When speaking about numbers of users, it’s also more correct to compare the number of questions tagged [tag:amazon-s3] and [tag:r], and suddenly your figures are inverted: R has 10 times more users. Sure, not every R question is about S3 but a substantial fraction (1%) is.

Comment: What’s more, you justifiably argue from misuse. That’s fair enough, but it’s just one side of the coin. There’s another side: Amazon S3 simply doesn’t *need* the [tag:s3] tag synonym. Sure, it’s useful for mistagging but it’s simply not essential. R, on the other hand, desperately *needs* the [tag:s3] tag, as evidenced by the number of questions tagged [tag:s4] and [tag:r6], and the number of questions that mention “S3” and which are *not* tagged [tag:r-s3] — in other words, you fear mistagging. But this mistagging is already rampant, in the other direction.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've rolled back your edit. The number wasn't incorrect - you're getting 1500 by searching for *posts* (includes answers), not *questions*. Compare http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+s3+is%3Aquestion with http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+s3. The number of *posts* tagged `amazon-s3` is over 30000; since we're comparing to the 15000 Amazon S3 questions, not the >30000 posts, the proper number to compare to for R's S3 is around 700 (or less if we want to exclude questions that mention Amazon).